# Trouble with unsigned char *

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with unsigned char *. Here is my code:

```
unsigned char *str=NULL;
str= (unsigned char*) realloc(str, 10*sizeof(unsigned char));
int number=10;
str[0]=(unsigned char) number;
```

Whenever I try to see str[0] with cout, it shows something else other than 10. I also have trouble when putting other variable into str:

```
unsigned char c='c';
str[0]=c;
cout<<str[0];
```

str[0] would output a. What am I missing?

Comment: You mean you put `'c'` in it and it shows you `a`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s[0] = 10;` means put character code `10` into the first location of array `s`. Try:

```
s[0] = '1'; s[1] = '0'; s[2] = '\0';
```

Probably you would like instead to use the function `itoa(10, s, 10);`

See itoa manual, the function itoa is declared as...

```
char* itoa(int valueToConvert, char* outputBuffer, int base);
```

If you try to do `cout << character`; it will print the character, not the character code. To print the character code you should do `cout << (int)character;`. Don't use `unsigned char` for characters, characters are, well, signed chars, simply chars, for friends.